# one form - add to two tables

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

how can i in Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine make one form, that will add data to two tables?
Default Symfony generated form for one table and module. at which point I can edit it and add their own fields?
http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/03
generated. 
i would like for example add field with new category.

```
# config/doctrine/schema.yml
JobeetCategory:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }

JobeetJob:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    category_id:  { type: integer, notnull: true }
     (...)
    expires_at:   { type: timestamp, notnull: true }
  relations:
    JobeetCategory: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: category_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: JobeetJobs }
```

this form add only id JobeetJob. how can i add into also JobeetCategory?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the JobeetCategory relation in the JobeetJob form. This will enable you to create a job and a category. Look for the `embedRelation()̀  method of the sfForm class.

Answer (score 1):

You should override save method in your model(Lets say in JobeetJob model). And save both models in transaction. Below I save to product and composite product tables. But dont forget that save method should has 2 functionality : **insert** and **update**

```
public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null){
  try {
      $conn->beginTransaction();

      $isNew = $this->isNew();         
      parent::save($conn); #Save Product

      $modelName = $this->moduleArray[$moduleName];

      $productId = $this->getId();

      if($isNew){ #CREATE new Composite Product and set Product ID and Module Name to it.

          $cp = new CompositeProduct();
          $cp->setRelatedModelID($productId);
          $cp->setRelatedModelName($modelName);
          $cp->setTitle($this->getTitle());
          $cp->save();

      }else{# UPDATE the Composite Product

          $query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('CompositeProduct')
                                ->createQuery('cp')
                                ->where('cp.relatedmodelname = ?',  $modelName)
                                ->andWhere('cp.relatedmodelid = ?', $productId);
          $cp = $query->fetchOne();

          $cp->setTitle($this->getTitle());
          $cp->save();
      }

      $conn->commit();
  }catch(Doctrine_Exception $e){
      $conn->rollback();
  }
```

}